# Checking if field data changed rather than any field in child data

Tags: android, web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can check if any data that is a child of my reference has changed no problem but I cant find a way to check if a certain field has changed within that child.

Here is some code the .child("job") does not work as job is the field. It was just somethin I was trying.

```
 Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

        //adding a value event listener so if data in database changes it does in textview also not needed at the minute
        ref.child("Driver").child("Driver2").child("job").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {


                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "YEAAA ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }

            /************had to implement this method****************/
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

here is the json from the database

```
  "Driver" : {
    "Driver1" : {
      "job" : "none",
      "lat" : 53.4013419,
      "lon" : -111.803055,
      "name" : "JOHNNY"
    },
    "Driver2" : {
      "job" : "job",
      "lat" : 53.4012956,
      "lon" : -6.4091191,
      "name" : "MICK"
    },
    "Driver3" : {
      "job" : "cccc",
      "lat" : 45.815399,
      "lon" : 15.966568,
      "name" : "Boris"
    }
  }
```

I want to check if the job field changes, as the coordinates fields will be constantly changing anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using correctly `addValueEventListener()` on the `reference` but you don't need that `for loop`. Your `DataSnapshot` is already on the `job child`, in which the key is `job` and the value is: `none`. So you need to remove the iteration. Hope it helps.

Comment: So you are saying I can take away the for loop, but then what code can I use to see if the value of job changes from none to something else? and not if anything under driver2 changes because the lat and lon are constantly changing

Comment: So if you want to display data from a Firebase database that is continually changing, i recomand you to use `FirebaseListAdapter`. Every change that is made is update automatically in a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I have no problem with the data that is changing, the only issue I have is that I was to trigger an event based on whether the job field changes.

Comment: So i specifically want to check if the job field changes rather than if any fields in Driver2 change

Comment: I understand, so this is how you need to do. You need put the `addValueEventListener()` on the correct child, as mentioned above and you will see only the changes on that particular field.

Comment: Thats the problem I have though, If if put it on the child Driver2 it checks all fields in Driver2, and it doesnt recognise .child("job") in the event listener

Comment: Use a `Toast` like this: `Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, snapshot.getValue().toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!